# External Monitor No Longer Detected After Laptop Screen Replacement

Tags: external-display, ubuntu-16.04, touchscreen

My set up, is that my HP Spectre x360 laptop is connected to an external monitor / mouse / ethernet via a hub. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

It usually works fine. Yesterday I had my cracked laptop screen replaced. Since then, I can't get the external monitor to be detected. Is it possible that having a new screen (touchscreen) on my laptop could have affected things?

Comment: I don't think so. It's more likely that the repairman has disconnected something he should have reconnected.

Comment: Concur with harrymc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen replacement is harmless, unless a mistake was made.
I have seen it being done several times by a professional with never a problem.

It's very likely that the repairman has disconnected something he should have reconnected.
Call him and complain loudly.